# ToStringBuilder doesn't print contents of nested objects

Tags: java

I am cuurently using apache commons API (commmons-lang.jar) to print an object values as shown below:

```
ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(object,ToStringStyle.MULTI_LINE_STYLE))
```

But this code does not print value if the object has a getter method which returns another object.

For example I have `Person` object it has a getter method which returns `Address` object. Using the above code, it just prints `Address` object name. I am looking for printing `Address` object values also. If I a pass `person.getAddress()` to above code it prints that but I want to see everything when I pass person object.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9):

Because it does not generate `toString` recursively. Either look for another tool, or just implement (or, better, IDE-autogenerate) the `Object#toString()` for all of them yourself.

For example:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private Address address;
    // Add/generate ctors, getters and setters.

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Person[name: %s, %s]", name, address);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Address {
    private String street;
    private String city;
    // Add/generate ctors, getters and setters.

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Address[street: %s, city: %s]", street, city);
    }
}
```

this way the

```
String personString = person.toString();
```

and

```
System.out.println(person);
```

would produce something like

```
Person[name: goutham, Address[street: Main Street 1, city: New York]]
```

Answer (score 9):

Since **version 3.2** of Apache Commons Lang, you can use a **`RecursiveToStringStyle`** to achieve exactly what you want.

Either:

```
ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(object, new RecursiveToStringStyle());
```

or

```
ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(object, new MultilineRecursiveToStringStyle());
```

`MultilineRecursiveToStringStyle` is available since **version 3.4**

Answer (score 5):

You can use this method to dump each objects

```
 public static String dump(Object object) {
    Field[] fields = object.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(object.getClass().getSimpleName()).append('{');

    boolean firstRound = true;

    for (Field field : fields) {
        if (!firstRound) {
            sb.append(", ");
        }
        firstRound = false;
        field.setAccessible(true);
        try {
            final Object fieldObj = field.get(object);
            final String value;
            if (null == fieldObj) {
                value = "null";
            } else {
                value = fieldObj.toString();
            }
            sb.append(field.getName()).append('=').append('\'')
                    .append(value).append('\'');
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ignore) {
            //this should never happen
        }

    }

    sb.append('}');
    return sb.toString();
}
```

If there are objects inside the object, pass obj1.obj2 as the argument.

Answer (score 2):

You can as well define a base class for all your classes that will define toString method in the following way:

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass{
  public String toString(){
    return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(object,ToStringStyle.MULTI_LINE_STYLE));
  }
}
```

And then just make your classes to extend it.
In such approach all your domain object will be able to generate a nice toString().

Comment: Down-vote from me. Java classes can only extend one object and to do so in order to make it a little easier to print seems criminal to me.